# How to build Evaluation Metrics Project from CETUS Challenge?

Tags: build, cmake, vtk

[CETUS](https://www.creatis.insa-lyon.fr/Challenge/CETUS/) is an open challenge on 3D echocardiography Segmentation. The goal is to segment some part of the volume of data provided for the challenge. To measure how successful you have been on segmentation, [a package](https://miccai.creatis.insa-lyon.fr/miccai/core/EvaluationMetrics.zip) is provided by the challenge which needs [VTK](https://www.vtk.org/download/) (Visualization Toolkit) to be contained in the project to be built.

I downloaded [VTK-8.1.1](https://www.vtk.org/files/release/8.1/VTK-8.1.1.zip) and compiled it using cmake and  visual studio 12 and added the path `project_directory/bin/release/` to windows 7 `path` environment variable.

When I try to `configure` challenge measurement project by cmake, it returns an error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (FIND_PACKAGE):
  By not providing "FindVTK.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "VTK", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "VTK" with any of
  the following names:

    VTKConfig.cmake
    vtk-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "VTK" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "VTK_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "VTK" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/MJ/Desktop/EvaluationMetrics/EvaluationMetrics/build_dir/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I don't know whether I should modify configurations in cmake for VTK, or perhaps the VTK I've downloaded is not a full version!

Can anyone help me to build measurement metrics project?

Comment: Does your VTK installation have the listed files (`VTKConfig.cmake` or `vtk-config.cmake`)? If so, set `VTK_DIR` as the error message suggests. Note, that VTK should be **installed**, not only *built*.

Comment: @Tsyvarev It contains `VTKConfig.cmake` but not `vtk-config.cmake`! Ok, I will add thi variable and try again.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I added `VTK_DIR` as suggested and also installed VTK project after ALL_BUILD in both Debug and Release modes. They where all done without errors. I opened Metric project again in cmake and configured and Generated without any errors.
Then I opened Project in visual studio and when I try to build ALL_BUILD in debug mode, It returns 40 errors such as: `error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'vtkProcessObject.h': No such file or directory`.

Comment: Have you checked that missed header files are actually existed in your VTK installation?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, I checked and they do not exist. This is why I guess my cmake configure should be wrong and something should be added to the project

Comment: VTK_DIR needs to set to binary directory in which you set cmake to build. If you run the INSTALL project that will dump all the binaries and includes to a Directory in your Program Files path - are you building shared libraries too?

Comment: @g.stevo No, I don't check Build shared libraries

Comment: You need that checked to build the DLLs etc you will reconfigure with that checked. Have a look at guides for building vtk in Windows fo more details